# Nonconstructive comments

Tags: discussion, comments

Should this forum run in a way where questions are unnecessarily scrutinized for their accuracy? At the end of the day, people have questions that need to be answered because of a lack of knowledge which will very often reflect in the question itself. Do we really want to scare people away from asking questions because of all the scrutiny that follows?
I've been on this forum off and on, and I often find the comments to questions nonconstructive. My initial reaction was to just abandon this forum, but this place is an amazing resource and it would be a shame if it turned people off.

Comment: As an aside, thank you for editing this question to be a discussion rather than a rant. Now it's an excellent question where we can address current community policy and possibly get some changes. Yelling at people never works.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the fact that in many questions the comments are so lenght and so numerous is strange. As if to comment questions is a professional activity, in a scholar universe. Perhaps mi yodeya is a school, the students came to learn how to ask, generally, how to think. But some persons want simply to know something. The CYLOR topic can teach us. When a posek is asked something, he cannot say, "Go home, and tomorow come back with a better version of your question".

To learn and teach Tora also is an open activity . If a bet midrash is for everybody, the rav will try to help  students even when they ask bad questions. "Sever panim yafot" is not to say  "welcome etc" this is a state of mind. The retoric of guidelines of comments is a bit inflated in mi yodeya. As if the comment say "mi yodeya is mine (my iodeya)" if you want to come in you need to allow with my personal standards.

We need to think about this bad side effect of the site.

Comment: it comes to appoint where you need think two or three times if you should ask a question. The level of scrutiny is definitely stifling.

Comment: I disagree, the point where one thinks before he acts or writes, is definitely not the end of the world.

Comment: @mevaqesh That is only if he eventually writes.